# How to list all unique user's session logged in stored in database Codeigniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter-3

I use Codeigniter framework to build my website. In Facebook and telegram we can show the list of session Logging In and detail (Devices name and OS platform name, ip address ...) And we can delete session to log out from another devices that we have logged in.

I have a session table set in session database $config

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id         | varchar(128)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ip_address | varchar(45)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| timestamp  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| data       | blob             | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

When user log in and loged out or logIn to another device how can I list these session?

Comment: What do you mean `how can I list these session`  - have you looked up the documentation  https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#accessing-session-metadata

Comment: I mean show all session data as Facebook session : https://db.tt/8FdJoM2nxW